# How to add a product under the specified category on the check out page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I want to do the following on the checkout/cart/ page:

When a visitor buy goods which order over $100, then I will add a free product to it. The free product is from a specified category. It will shows under the bought product. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the MageWorld Free Gift extension. From your description, I believe that will do what you need. However, the extension is not free.
http://www.mage-world.com/free-gift-magento-extension.html

If you want to develop this functionality yourself, I'd suggest you extend the shopping cart promo rules. The rule itself will check whether the order is over $100. You just have to develop the part which will select a free product from a category you specify.

Comment: i am sorry i am new to mangento,if i want to extend the shopping cart promo rules. The rule itself will check whether the order is over $100.could you give me with more detail. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to listen on a quote save with an observer and add / remove the free product that way. First, setup a new module named Yrcrz/AddFreeProduct. In the config.xml, add:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sales_quote_save_before</method>
                    </Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

This defines the event `sales_quote_save_before` that we will be listening for. Then, add an Observer.php file and add this:

```
<?php

class Yrcrz_AddFreeProduct_Model_Observer
{
    public function sales_quote_save_before(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $freeProductId = 182;
        $threshold = 100;
        $freeProductExists = false;
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $freeProductId) {
                $realGrandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal() - $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
                if ($realGrandTotal < $threshold) {
                    $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
                    return false;
                }
                $freeProductExists = true;
            }
        }

        if ($freeProductExists || !$items) {
            return false;
        }

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        if ($quote->getGrandTotal() >= $threshold) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($freeProductId);
            if ($product && $product->getId()) {
                $params = array();
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $cart->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code checks to see if the threshold ($100) is reached, and if so it adds a product. It will also remove the free product if the grand total is under the threshold or there are no products. Note that you will need to define the ID of the free product with `$freeProductId`.

Comment: many thanks,when i created the module,i don't know where to put the Observer.php file in? thank you

Comment: Observer.php should be placed in app/code/local/Yrcrz/AddFreeProduct/Model/

Comment: i also need create YrcrzAddFreeProduct.xml in \app\etc\modules.am i right?

Comment: now, i want to extend your code, the $freeProductId i want to from a category, eg:$categoryId = 123;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); how to add the code to your code?

Comment: if i want to add other conditions, eg: if the threshold ($200) is reached, and if so it adds tow products. if the threshold ($500) is reached, and if so it adds three product. how do i do? many thanks.

Comment: Creation of a simple Magento module: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: You want a random product from that category? Also, the adding of these other products is quite simple but this is where I'll leave you. You need to just add a couple other if statements to do the check - nothing too complicated.

Comment: yes,your are right.i want  a random product from that category.i will put my code in my question.

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to php, i don't know how to write the elseif body,could you help me? many thanks.

Comment: Did the code not work or are you disappointed because I didn't continue to answer your other questions?

Comment: no,the code is real not work.when the order is bigger than 100,it can't invoke the id is 182 product